# How to upload my ArcGIS Server web map to free domain?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

i have created web map with arcgis server version 10.1, i just want to know how to upload this map from local url to free domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider ArcGIS Online for hosting your map. They have various license levels and you should be able to add it to your Esri account (if not already there).

Otherwise I don't know of any free hosts that offer ArcGIS Server. Other companies, e.g. Geocortex, can host your application(s) and service(s), but don't offer free hosting.